# Conditional Indicator based on row number

Tags: r, conditional-statements, row

i have this data frame below. I want to make a column, where if ind_2 = 1 first, before any of the other rows, then put a 1.

| row number | ind_1 | ind_2 | ind_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

desired output:

| row number | ind_1 | ind_2 | ind_3 | master_ind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: What have you tried, where did you encounter problems in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You could check `which` row has the first value with 1 and check based on the `row_number` if it needs to return a 1 or 0 like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(master_ind = ifelse(row_number() == min(which(ind_2 == 1)), 1, 0))
#>   row_number ind_1 ind_2 ind_3 master_ind
#> 1          1     0     0     0          0
#> 2          2     0     1     0          1
#> 3          3     1     0     0          0
#> 4          4     0     1     1          0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: alternative: `df1 %>% 
  mutate(master_ind = +(rownumber == which(ind_2 == 1)[1]))`

Answer (score 1):

We may use `base R` to do this

```
df1$master_ind <- +( df1[,2] == 0 &
     apply(df1[-1], 1, \(x) sum(cumsum(x[-1] == 1) == 1)) > 1
)
```

-output

```
 df1
  rownumber ind_1 ind_2 ind_3 master_ind
1         1     0     0     0          0
2         2     0     1     0          1
3         3     1     0     0          0
4         4     0     1     1          0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(rownumber = 1:4, ind_1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), ind_2 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), ind_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(master_ind = +(rownumber == match(1, df1$ind_2)))

  rownumber ind_1 ind_2 ind_3 master_ind
1         1     0     0     0          0
2         2     0     1     0          1
3         3     1     0     0          0
4         4     0     1     1          0
```